# How to prove $\inf_{z\in\mathbb{R}^n}h(z)=\inf_{x\in{C}}f(x)$ for the function $h(z)=\min_{x\in{C}}\{f(x)+\frac{1}{2}||x-z||^2\}$

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have a problem related to convex optimization. I have a function where $h(z)=\min_{x\in{C}}\{f(x)+\frac{1}{2}||x-z||^2\}$ for all $z\in{\mathbb{R}^n}$. For this function, I want to show $\inf_{z\in\mathbb{R}^n}h(z)=\inf_{x\in{C}}f(x)$.

I tried to connect this problem to proximal point method because the format of the function $h(z)$ is the same as the form of the objective function in that method. By using proximal method, I mean that I tried to find relevant information in the steps of the proof of that method, but I did not have much of a success.

Another idea which I was told was to look at the problem in a different way, which I could not make a connection with the original problem and the suggested idea. The idea is about the fact that we can write a vector $y\in{\mathbb{R}}^n$ as $y=y_1+y_2$, where $y_1\in{\mathbb{R}^{n_1}}$ and $y_2\in{\mathbb{R}^{n_2}}$ and $n_1+n_2=n$. We can perform the minimization of a function with domain $y$ in two phases: first minimize over $y_1$, and then minimize over $y_2$.
I can not establish a clear connection between the idea explained above and the original problem.

If anyone can help with solving this problem, I would be very thankful!

Comment: $\inf_{x\in A}\inf_{y\in B}\Phi(x, y)= \inf_{y\in B}\inf_{x\in A}\Phi(x,y)$

Comment: @OliverDiaz Would you mind giving a bit more explanation, please?

Comment: I think that what @OliverDiaz tried to say is:
$\inf_{z \in \mathbb{R}^n} h(z) = \inf_{z \in \mathbb{R}^n} \inf_{x \in C} f(x) + 0.5 \lVert x-z \rVert^2 = \inf_{x \in C} \inf_{z \in \mathbb{R}^n}  f(x) + 0.5 \lVert x-z \rVert^2 = \inf_{x \in C}  f(x)$

Comment: @JinraeKim How did you conclude the last equality?

Comment: @NBS In $f(x) + 0.5 \lVert x-z \rVert^2$, the only $z$-related term is $\lVert x-z \rVert^2$ and $z=x$ attains the minimum, obviously.

Comment: @JinraeKim, I see! Thank you! This solution is indeed way more straight forward than mine!

Comment: @OliverDiaz Is there any requirement for the function $\Phi(x,y)$? Separability of the variables, for example?

Comment: @NBS: No, it works in full generality.

Comment: @AlexM. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to supply some details at the request the OP to my comment to his/her question.

---

Suppose $\Phi:A\times B\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and that $\Phi$ is bounded below. Let
\begin{align}
\alpha&=\inf_{(x,y)\in A\times B}\Phi(x,y)\\
\beta&=\inf_{x\in A}\inf_{y\in B}\Phi(x,y)
\end{align}
The claim is that $\alpha=\beta$.

Notice that as $\Phi(x,y)\geq \alpha$ for all $(x,y)\in A\times B$. Then,  for $x'\in A$
$$\phi(x'):=\inf_{y\in B}\Phi(x',y)\geq \alpha$$
and so,
$$\beta=\inf_{x\in A}\phi(x)=\inf_{x\in A}\inf_{y\in B}\Phi(x,y)\geq \alpha$$

Conversely, for any $(x',y')\in A\times B$,
$$\Phi(x',y')\geq \phi(x')=\inf_{y\in B}\Phi(x',y)$$
Since $\phi(x')\geq \inf_{x\in A}\phi(x)$, we have that
$$\Phi(x',y')\geq \inf_{x\in A}\inf_{y\in B}\Phi(x,y)=\beta$$
It then follows that
$$\alpha=\inf_{(x,y)\in A\times B}\Phi(x,y)\geq \beta$$
by definition of $\inf$.

Putting things together, $\alpha=\beta$

A similar identity can be obtained by changing the order in the infirma, that is
$$\delta:=\inf_{y\in B}\inf_{x\in A}\Phi(x,y)=\inf_{(x,y)\in A\times B}\Phi(x,y)=\alpha$$

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is the following:

We can prove that a function in the form $h(z)=\min\limits_{x\in{C}}\{f(x)+\frac{1}{2}\|x-z\|^{2}\}$ for all $z\in\mathbb{R}^n$ has a unique solution for each $x\in{C}$, and attains its minimum.
We set $g(x)=f(x)+\frac{1}{2}\|x-z\|^{2}$. So, we can write:

$$h(z)=\min\limits_{x\in{C}}g(x)=\inf\limits_{x\in{C}}g(x),~\forall{z\in{\mathbb{R}^n}}$$
With optimality condition, we have:
$\langle{\nabla{f(x^*)}+\|x^*-z\|},x-x^*\rangle\geq{0}$.
Since $C\subseteq{\mathbb{R}^n}$, we can set $z=x^*$. (I missed to mention this in the question.)
$$\langle{\nabla{f(x^*)},x-x^*}\rangle\geq0$$
Thus, we have:
$$\inf\limits_{z\in\mathbb{R}^n}h(z)=\inf\limits_{x\in{C}}g(x)$$.

Comment: The one-line solution is the one suggested in Oliver Diaz's comment.

Comment: @AlexM. I tried to understand how to use  that statement in order to solve the problem. I was not successful!